# Raising and Handling events across multiple instances using axonframework

Tags: http, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I have just started exploring event based proramming with axonframework. I see there is support for raising and handling events.

I have a scenario where there are multiple services communicating with each in different instance/jvm using  http.

I now want to use events for service communication. I am not sure how we can pass events across the network and have them handled by services running in different jvm/host.

Does axonframework provide any support for this or should I be integrating directly with messaging middleware for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axon does provide support for this, although in some cases, you would still require messaging middleware. Axon focuses on the APIs, more than on the messaging itself.

If you use an Event Store, you can store the events you publish, and have different nodes read from that store (at their own pace). Axon supports Event Stores based on JPA/JDBC and MongoDB.

If you don't want/need to store your events, you can use a Message Broker instead. Axon supports AMQP message brokers via Spring AMQP. Axon will do the serialization/deserialization of messages for you.

The benefit from Axon in this case, is that it abstracts the messaging implementation away from the business logic. The business logic just publishes an Event to the Event Bus, whereafter Axon publishes it to the configured broker.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Can you please  point me to a sample or to the docs on how the event bus abstracts the mapping of events to topics on the producer and comsumer side.

Comment: Check out the reference guide: https://docs.axonframework.org/part3/event-processing.html#distributing-events